# Convention for passing arguments to non-Silicon subblocks/helpers

Tags: origen-sdk

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, but what are the options/conventions that Origen provides for setting up subblocks that aren't necessarily silicon models, or are just general helpers?

For example, I have a scan helper plugin that guides the user through creating a scan test program. I'd like to add a list of options/customizations to the top-level app. There are a few ways to do this:

1. I can add a list of attr_readers/methods. I think this looks a bit ugly though and adds a bunch of stuff to the toplevel that isn't used by anything else, and it blows up $dut.methods.
2. I could use parameters as defined here: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/ and just call of them in the scan tester app. But looking at the guides I don't think that is the desired use case. It looks more like context switching, but maybe that was just the example use case.
3. I could add a scan_tester.setup method or something on the toplevel. This just seems unnecessary though since its basically doing the same thing as #2, but requires a 'setup' method to be called. Yeah, its only 1 line, but if you mess up or forget to add that line then you've got some debug to do avoided by #2 (I can print a warning for example if the scan parameters aren't provided to help warn of typos, etc.).
4. I can set it up as a subblock (currently how I've got it), but this doesn't really fit. Scan isn't a silicon model, so base address is useless, but required. It has no registers, etc.

Then there's other 'Ruby' things I could do (setup via on_create, use global variable etc.) but these all seem not as great as any of the options above for one reason or another (mainly, more setup required on my part than using any of the existing options).

Any one of these would work. But from a convention standpoint, which direction should my scan tester setup go? Is there another option I hadn't considered? I'd lean towards option #2 as it looks the cleanest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really good question.

There are actually two other options:

5. Add application config parameters from the plugin: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/release_notes/#v0_7_24
6. Define a constant as used by the JTAG and other early plugins: http://origen-sdk.org/jtag/#How_To_Use

I think #2 is using parameters in a way that was not originally intended, maybe it could work though but I just can't picture it.

I don't really like #5 or #6 since they provide application-level and class-level configuration, which is sometimes what you want, but often these days I see the need more for (DUT) instance-level configuration.

So, my best answer here is that I don't know, but you are touching on a good point that we need to have an official API or at least a recommendation for this.

I think you should be open to the possibility of adding something new to Origen for this if you can think of something better.

As I'm writing this, I suppose #5 would also support instance-level configuration, albeit a bit long-winded:

```rb
def initialize(options = {})
  Origen.app.config.scan_chain_length = 6
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To me, #5, seems a lot like just defining the attr_readers, but blows up $dut.config instead. Though that's not a huge problem, its not ideal. I've tried to stay pretty clear of constants (and global variables for that matter) so that if something else tries to define the same, it won't be overridden. Though that too would work. I liked the subblocks because it had a nice compact method to call, could easily be queried by Origen, printed nicely, had errors for redefining, etc. If this is a gap in Origen I can look at adding something.

Comment: What would you think of a 'component' API. For example, we could have:

# components.rb
component(scan, TIPScan, options)

then we can do things like:

$dut.scan #=> TIPScan instance
$dut.component(:scan) #=> same as above
$dut.components #=> [TIPScan instance, ...]
$dut.has_component(:scan) #=> true
etc.

Pretty much just a stripped down subblock class to handle these. I think our IAR/C compilers and even CATI could benefit from this and make the setup cleaner and more customizable.

Answer (score 1):

My comment wouldn't keep its format, so here it is but looks better:

@Ginty

What would you think of a 'component' API. For example, we could have:

```
# components.rb 
component(:scan, TIPScan::ScanTester, 
    # options
    wgl_dir: ..., # defaults to Origen.app.root/pattern/wgl
    custom_sort: proc do {|wgl_name| ...},
) 

# then we can do things like: 
$dut.scan #=> TIPScan instance 
$dut.component(:scan) #=> same as above 
$dut.components #=> [TIPScan instance, ...] 
$dut.has_component(:scan) #=> true etc.
```

Pretty much just a stripped down subblock class to handle these. I think our IAR/C compilers and even CATI could benefit from this and make the setup cleaner and more customizable.

Comment: Moved the discussion over to Github - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/issues/141

Comment: We created our own custom TestModules class to handle a similar concept.  Because we don't use Origen to create patterns (yet), we needed a model to house the test method parameters specific to various types of test such as scan.